# Cannot form keyvalue pair in javascript in desired format

Tags: javascript

I have formed a keyvalue pair in JavaScript using the below code:

```
for(i=1;i<=results.totpage;i++)
     {
       pushToAry(i,i);

     }
```

Assume results.totpage as 300.
The method **pushToAry():**

```
function pushToAry(name, val) {
//alert("In the array");
   var obj = {};
   obj[name] = val;
   ary.push(obj);  
}
```

where ary is defined as **var ary = [];**
Using the above format the result that comes out is like:

[image]

But I want to make it like `[["key1", "value1"],["key2", "value2"],["key3", "value3"]]` i.e. to replace the 2nd brackets with the 3rd brackets.

Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want an array of arrays instead of an array of objects? Then you want your key to be at position 0 and your value at position 1?

Comment: have a look at http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/studio/kony_widget_user_guide/Content/ListBox_Basic_Properties.htm ,the masterdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing a object to `ary`, push a new array:

```
var ary = [];

function pushToAry(name, val) {
    //alert("In the array");
   var arr = [name, val];
   ary.push(arr);  
}
```